# How to hide or show column of table created using datatables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Do you know how to hide or show column when datatable's source is javascript?

Methods for showing or hiding columns

```
 table = $('#example').DataTable();
var col = table.column("0").visible(false);
```

work when data source is directly into html

```
<table id="example" class="row-border hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
...
```

But it does not work and launch an error  when DataTable has a javascript source

```
 var table = $('#example').dataTable({
                   "data": source,
                    "columns": columns,
                    "columnDefs": defs
    });


 var col = table.column("0").visible(false);//ERROR!
```

Do you know how to hide a column of Datatables with a javascript source please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found another answere :  it doesn't depends of html or json source but there is a difference between DataTable() which is the new version and dataTable() the old version

```
column(n).visible(bool)
```

works for DataTable()

```
fnRowCallback
```

works for dataTable()

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
  "data": source,
  "columns": columns,
  "columnDefs": [
  {
    "targets": [ 0 ],
    "visible": false,
  },
  "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull )     
  {
    $('td:eq(0)', nRow).hide();
  }
});
```

Updated. Try to add fnRowCallback. thanks!